# Excel script does not follow logic

Tags: excel

I don't know how to access the code in excel. But logically, this is suposed to work. I don't see the problem. I want to add a new date for my new project. Excel says that there is a problem with the formula. But I don't understand why.

The cell formula for start date is:
=MIN(IF((Tasks[Project]=[@Project])*(Tasks[Start]>0),Tasks[Start]))
I don't know what it means

[image: Excel date illogic]

Comment: Im not sure if I understand this question correctly, but if this is VBA-related, please add your code. We can't debug a VBA script or a formula that we don't know of, sorry...

Comment: You're seriously expecting us to guess what you're asking or debug your VBA from an image of a spreadsheet?

Comment: =MIN(IF((Tasks[Project]=[@Project])*(Tasks[Start]>0),Tasks[Start]))

Comment: @pnuts , what do you mean by double click, what will it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a standard Excel formula, using *Structured Referencing* to reference Tables in the workbook.

There will be a table elsewhere (probably on the `Task Details` tab) called `Tasks`, with columns called `Project` and `Start`

`Tasks[Project]` refers to the `Tasks` table, whole of the column calld `Project`
`Tasks[Start]` refers to the `Tasks` table, whole of the column calld `Start`
`@Project` refers to the table the formula is in, column `Project`, same row as the formula.  Since this formula is in the pictured table, `Start` column, eg in cell `E4` this would refer to `EBook`

For each cell in `Start` column, the formula lookup up the `Tasks` table, for projects that match that row, and returns the earliest start date from `Tasks`, `Start` column